# Bring an open window to the current desktop in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

Let's say I have a program open on another virtual desktop. Is there a way I can bring that program to the current desktop through a script?

The following command is the closest I can get:

```
wmctrl -a program
```

This will switch to the desktop where the program is open and make it the foremost window. However, instead of going to the desktop where the program is, I want to bring the program to the current desktop. There is also this command:

```
wmctrl -R program
```

The documentation says that this will do what I want, but it just does the same thing as the former command.

Comment: Are you using Gnome as your window manager? (It is the default one for Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the `-R` switch works fine when using Metacity (the default window manager for GNOME) but not so much when using Compiz (the default window manager nowadays for Ubuntu I believe). You can check this out yourself by switching to Metacity using `metacity --replace` (use `compiz --replace` to switch back to Compiz).

Irritatingly enough I haven't been able to figure out *why* this doesn't work with Compiz, I still thought it would be nice to share what I've found out so far, which is:

- For me `wmctrl -d` lists a desktop geometry (DG) of 7680x1200 (I have a resolution of 1920x1200 and use 4 workspaces).

  In this case one could move the window to the second workspace by using `wmctrl -e 0,1920,-1,-1,-1` (gravity, pixels from left, pixels from top, window width, window height -- the value `-1` is used to indicate that the current value should not be modified).

  You can among other things use `wnckprop` or `xwininfo` to get the geometry values for the current window.
- With the `Put` plugin activated one can use the following command to move the current active/focused window to the second workspace (viewport?):

  `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/put/allscreens/put_viewport_2_key org.freedesktop.compiz.activate`

That's pretty much it, hopefully somebody else can offer more insight into the matter.

**Related**

- [Stack Overflow: How to programmatically switch to a specific window in compiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000050/how-to-programmatically-switch-to-a-specific-window-in-compiz)

**Resources**

- [Launchpad: Bug #533704 in wmctrl (Ubuntu): “wmctrl:Setting virtual workspace/desktop/viewport.”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wmctrl/+bug/533704)
- [Compiz Community Forums: place-windows.sh (Window Placing Script)](http://forum.compiz.org/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=11927#)
- [Compiz Wiki: Plugins/Dbus](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus)
- [Compiz Community Forums: A script for activating compiz actions over D-Bus](http://forum.compiz.org/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=7359)